# SysV Init killall5 does not wake up after sleep 5

Tags: linux-kernel, sleep, yocto

I have created a custom embedded Linux distro using Yocto based on Poky. I am using SysVInit utilities. When we restart the system and all the rc6 scripts are called. Almost in the end /etc/init.d/sendsigs script is called. This script first send SIGTERM signal to all the running processes and sleep for 5 seconds and then send SIGKILL signal to all the remaining processes. The problem I am seeing is when I restart the system, the script send SIGTERM signal and sleep for 5 seconds but does not wake up after the sleep hence it does not send SIGTERM and hangs the system causing system not to reboot. Following is the /etc/init.d/sendsigs script

```
echo "Sending TERM signal..."
killall5 -15
sleep 5     # Does not wakeup after sleep.
echo "Sending KILL signal..."
killall5 -9
```

It looks like kernel scheduler does not wake up the script process. But any ideas where should I be looking to fix the issue or where the problem could possibly be.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause of this bug and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. In my case, the problem was there was a process still running that used the network stack when K80networking was called. The kernel lockup wouldn't occur until the shutdown got to the sleep 5 in sendsigs. Curiously, replacing sleep 5 with sleep 1 called five times in sendsigs worked around the issue.